# Swift_TransportException: Cannot send message without a sender address Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, mail

Que es lo que tengo que cambiar en mi archivo .env para poder enviar mail?

MAIL_MAILER estaba como MAIL_MAILER=smtp y lo cambie a MAIL_MAILER=log, lo cambie para que me envie en el log el resultado del mail.

Estoy usando la version 7 de laravel segun tengo entendido el MAIL_DRIVER fue cambiado por el MAIL_MAILER

Esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo .env del proyecto

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:fmT3dL+Uhb0su5Vpetm2tv2RFqF/0PxP9kY9scCu1L0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=log
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mimail@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="API Restful"

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=-----
MAILGUN_SECRET=-----

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

esto es lo que tengo en el archivo que me envia a la vista que me genera el correo, este codigo lo que deberia hacer es que al momento de crear un nuevo usuario, este llame al emails/welcome.blade.php para que me genere el texto del mail de notificacion:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\User;

class UserCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user= $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.welcome')->subject('Por favor confirma tu correo electronico');
    }
}
```

esto es lo que tengo en mi emails/welcome.blade.php:

```
Hola {{$user->name}}
Gracias por crear una cuenta. Por favor verifiquela usando el siguiente enlace.

{{route('verify', $user->verification_token)}}
```

esto lo que deberia hacer es tomar los datos del usuario recien creado y generar el texto con los datos en el laravel.log

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar emails solo tienes que configurar toda la parte del correo, el driver, username, password, etc en si es lo mismo y el envio de emails se llama de la misma manera.

Puedes usar para pruebas https://mailtrap.io/signin te brinda la informacion necesaria para que puedas enviar emails, y en una bandeja de entrada que se te crea recibes emails que envies desde tu aplicacion

Esto es un ejemplo de lo que te arroja

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=5da4f3
MAIL_PASSWORD=61b2
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: yo tenia MAIL_MAILER=log, para que en el laravel.log me lleguen los mensajes que enviaba en vez de usar mailtrap.io

Comment: Entonces no e entendido del todo bien, quieres que sea por log? en vez de por smtp  o algo?

Comment: Todo lo que tendrias que hacer es al enviar email es  `Log::info($message);`

Comment: acabo de editar la consulta agregando el codigo que tengo

Comment: reinicie el servidor cerrando el editor de codigo, funciono

Comment: Ok ps entonces ya esta xd